# Cant store data locally using microsoft powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I am having some trouble storing data to my local device on my microsoft powerapps app.

The application I am creating is a survey application where a user can fill in a form and tap submit to ideally store their entry onto a table which can be viewed on a seperate page.

I have been able to get as far as creating the form and storing the data locally in a collection however this only stores the data on the device whilst the app is open, as soon as the app is closed the data stored is gone.

The question is whether there is a more efficient way to store any data collected from my app onto the device where it can be saved even if the application is closed?

Any comments/answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Collections are designed to represent some context for the app at runtime, and are not meant to "store data". You could use the "Import/Export" controls and save and restore collections, but the user has to manually click them.

What you can do is connect to an external data source, such as CDS, or an excel file on OneDrive/Google Drive/Dropbox, etc. and save your data there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have previously developed login app demo by using SharePoint and PowerApps together, the data exchange between these two platforms are simply seamless.
SharePoint can serve as a database for your application and there is template available for direct connection between these two :)

Reference:

[My login app demo](http://www.edwardhk.com/ms-office/login-page-using-sharepoint-powerapps/)

[Official documentation](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-and-sharepoint/)